# Benefit from Selector and implement custom onClick() behaviour

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I have a `ListView` that I populate with multiple elements by using the view holder pattern. I have specified a `Selector` to change the background colour of the selection. When the user has selected an item (or not) and chosen to continue to the next `Activity` in my control flow, I want to retrieve what he selected and feed it to my business logic.

My dilemma is as follows: When I use methods like `AdapterView#getSelectedItem()` they return `null`. What I would require, I think, is to check what item is activated, not selected, but there does not seem to be a method for that. At least not that I can find. If I then proceed to set an `OnClickListener` in my adapter and override `onClick`, the `Selector` will seize to work. I could use methods to set the listview's item to active but then I face the problem of toggling selections; basically what I had wanted to use the `Selector` in the first place.

Here a bit of code:

`persona_selector.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_activated="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" android:state_activated="true" />
</selector>
```

`DemoPersonaAdapter.java`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentViewGroup)
{       
    final PersonaViewHolder viewHolder;
    final Persona persona = provider[position];

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_personas, null);

        viewHolder = new PersonaViewHolder(
                (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_icon),
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_description));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (PersonaViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), persona.getPicture());
    viewHolder.setIcon(icon, 50, 50);
    viewHolder.setDescription(persona.getName() + " is a " + persona.getType() + "!");

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            ((ParentClass)parent).setPersona(persona);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Did you implemented listener for LIstView?

Comment: No. The `ListView` is not selected, its elements are.

Comment: what do you mean by activated item?

Comment: I mean the state of the item that the `Selector` uses to set the background colour: `android:state_activated`. I presume that the `onClick` behaviour by default for single selection `ListView` sets the states of all items to be inactive before setting the one you selected to active again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a global [item click listener on the list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) instead of a per view click listener?

Comment: Because, in my opinion, I shouldn't need to use the container to specify behaviour of specific children. It is what I'd call bad design. However, your solution solves my problem. Thank you for the different view on the issue!